# Dividing electrical potential by zero at the origin

Tags: equation-solving

I am evaluating the electric potential as a function of position within a spherically symmetric charge distribution that drops off exponentially with distance.  The result I get works fine, and plots well.  However, at r = 0, I get the error: "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>

```
In[13]:= pot_\[Rho]V[r_] = -Integrate[eField[r], r ]

Out[13]= -E^(-2.*10^10 r) (14.4049 + 1.44049*10^-9/r) + 1.44049*10^-9/
   r
```

Is this something I just notice and leave it - which is OK - or is there a way to cast the expression such that the two 1/r factors cancel when r = 0, as they should?  The correct answer is just -14.4049 @ r=0.  Thanks, Jack

Comment: This is a problem of simple analytical mathematics, not a *Mathematica* issue.

Answer (score 7):

Say your function is:

```
f[r_] := -E^(-2.*10^10 r) (14.4049 + 1.44049*10^-9/r) + 1.44049*10^-9/r
```

To find the value at r=0, take:

```
Limit[f[r], r -> 0]

14.4049
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The expression for the function returned by your integration has a "removable singularity" at zero.  This is not a problem with the function itself, merely the expression that Mathematica has returned.  I don't believe that Mathematica has a specific way of dealing with this case (unlike `Sin[x]/x == Sinc[x]`).

If you have

```
expr = -E^(-2.*10^10 r) (14.4049 + 1.44049*10^-9/r) + 1.44049*10^-9/r
```

you can define

```
f[r_]=expr;
```

but evaluating

```
f[0]
```

gives `Indeterminate`.  However you can simply define

```
f[0] = Limit[f[r], r -> 0]
```

and it will now return the appropriate value.

Comment: Yes, OK I am still not well versed in Mathematica - I did figure a limit like this might be the approach.  Thanks.